# Требуется вывод введенных данных с contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form7

Появилась задача валидации веденных данных клиентом. То есть клиент вводит свои данные в контактной форме ( Contact form 7 ) , его перенаправляет на страницу спасибо, где должны быть указаны его введенные данные , чтобы он убедился в их правильности. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы реализовать данный функционал, Вам нужно предотвратить отправку данных плагином contact form 7 и извлечь данные. Для этого необходимо воспользоваться услугами js.

1. Вешаем на форму событие `submit`
2. Предотвращаем отправку формы
3. Формируем массив для отправки на страницу "Спасибо"
4. Создаём фиктивную форму с `action` на нашу страницу
5. Добавляем в неё данные и отправляем её.
6. На страницы спасибо, считываем POST запрос и выводим данные в новую форму contactform7 которая уже будет отправлять данные на почту
7. Завариваем кружечку кофе ;)

Пример кода на JQuery:

```
function validateCF7() {
   $("#myBestFrom").submit(function(e) {  // 1
       e.preventDefault(); // 2
       var requestData = [];
       $(this).find("input").each(function() { // можно добавлять textarea, select и 
           //т.д
           requestData.push($(this).val());  // 3
       });
       var url = 'http://example.com/thanks';
       var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
           '<input type="text" name="cf7_data" value="' + JSON.stringify(requestData) + '" />' +
           '</form>');
       $('body').append(form);
       form.submit();  // 4, 5
   });
}
```

На странице "Спасибо":

```
$inputDataJson = $_POST["cf7_data"] ?? false; // если 7+ php!
// иначе проверяйте на isset() и is_null()
if (!$inputDataJson) {
    //redirect или еще что-то
    wp_die(); // или exit()
}
$inputData = json_decode($inputDataJson)

//Вывод через цикл данных в форму!
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас буду разбираться )